# Return the string is invalid for four times consecutive repetition of a digit using Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I think I am too close to the solution. (Need a push!)

```
import re

for _ in range(int(input())):
    match = re.findall(r'^([456])((\d){3}(-)?(\d){4}(-)?(\d){4}(-)?(\d){4})(?!.*\1\2){3}$', input())
    if match:
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")
```

I will explain my understanding of the regex I wrote, wrt to the problem asked.

- The string must start with 4,5 or 6 - **Regex**: r'^([456])
- Must contain exactly 16 digits and it may have digits in groups of 4, separated by one hyphen "-"

  **Regex**:((\d){3}(-)?(\d){4}(-)?(\d){4}(-)?(\d){4})
- Must only consist of digit 0-9
- Must not use any separator like `"_"` `" "` etc.
- It must not have 4 or more consecutive repeated digits - **Regex**: (?!.*\1\2){3}$

  - Valid: 4123456789123456
  - Valid: 5123-4567-8912-3456
  - Invalid: 61234-567-8912-3456 (as it doesn't form a group of 4 {61234})
  - Valid: 4123356789123456
  - Invalid: 5133-3367-8912-3456

  (The problem is it is accepting four (3333)
  because it is occurring before and after the hyphen) In the output screen after the execution this above string is also showing valid which it shouldn't.

If I am missing out on the other mentioned conditions in the regex please share your answers on that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Must not use any separator like "_" " " etc." This on seems to be missing.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand because "the string must start with 456" conflicts with what you list as valid.  I came up with ^(\d{4})[\-\s]?(456\d)([\-\s]?[0-9]{4}){2}$ but this may not help - probably because I don't see a clear "match all of these [list 10 or 20 strings] and don't match these [list another close but different strings]"

Comment: @Eraklon, if I will add the separator part still the consecutive repetition problem, would not be solved.

Comment: @Sheeban Undeniable, for that I tried this `^([456])(?!(?:\1-?){3})(?:(\d)(?!(?:\2-?){3})){3}(((?:-)?(?:(\d)(?!(\3-?){3})){4})){3}$` which seems to work but did not duble checked it (https://regex101.com/r/0fgOWA/10)

Comment: @Eraklon thanks for working out but it failed.

Comment: @Sheeban On what input?

Comment: the input string of numbers mentioned in the question @Eraklon

Comment: @Sheeban Hmm seems like good to me. Did you checked the link?

Comment: @Eraklon yes I checked the link. It is working but when I am running the regex on personal Ide it shows an error: cannot refer to an open group at position 68 :(

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

```
^(\d{4})([\-]?[0-9]{4}){3}$
```

Or if the second group (not the start) must be 4567 try...

```
^(\d{4})[\-]?(4567)([\-\s]?[0-9]{4}){2}$
```

Comment: can you edit your questions and put below the original text a list of valid numbers and then a list of possible values that should be seen as invalid?  put "Valid:" and a plain text list, then "Invalid:" and a plain text list so no other values creep in

Comment: hope I made myself clear as I edited the question. I can come again if needs more clarification on the question. Thanks.

Comment: Still unsure.  Why is 5123-4567-8912-3456 valid, but 5133-3367-8912-3456 invalid?  You mention "...33-33..." but is this not allowed?  If so you have to explain what is allowed here.  The first three, second three, three-threes, four?  A 3 in the third position?  The allow numbers and their exact order has to be known. :o(

Comment: sorry, re-reading your post.  so any number can only repeat three times?

Comment: The conditions I mentioned we need to follow that we can leave a specific string for now.

Comment: It must not have 4 or more consecutive repeated digits. Whatever may be the input all the conditions mentioned must be satisfied. My regex satisfied all the conditions except the consecutive repetition of the digits.

Comment: OK, got you.  Too complex (if it can be done) with regex for me.  I'd suggest something like taking the input, removing dashes to get a pure number string, match for repeating number (like (\d)\1{4} or similar) and then, if it passes that, match with your regex or the above for validation card number.  Sorry.  :o(

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I am up with the answer. Thanks for the help everyone.

```
import re
for _ in range(int(input())):
    s = input()
    if re.match(r"^[456]([\d]{15}|[\d]{3}(-[\d]{4}){3})$", s) and not re.search(r"([\d])\1\1\1", s.replace("-", "")):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")
```